# Which is more valuable, gold or elixer?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Which is more valuable, Gold or Elixir? I am wondering which one to protect the most.

(In the context of which is used more, which one can be more readily acquired, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gold is generally considered more valuable as more upgrades require it where elixir is generally only used for research and troop hire.

I would say elixir is easier to acquire from raids, mainly due to the above point, it isn't used as much and therefore players usually have more stored up.

Look at [this](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Cumulative_Costs) link in the 'Totals' subsection. It gives total gold at 2.8 billion, where elixir is 'just' 348 million. So by that logic gold is almost exactly 8 times as valuable (assuming you generate it at the same rate).

Comment: In my opinion it's harder acquire elixir from raids. A raid costs a couple thousands of gold for finding an enemy. But the cost for training troops for the raid (especially when you use spells) is almost as high as the gain.

Comment: @raznagul - That's true, but you also have to look at bases and the possible resource haul you can get from one attack. Typically you will see people with more elixir than gold (like 60k/150k). It probably will change more now that walls can be upgraded with elixir at lvl 6+ though...

Answer (score 0):

Gold is used to upgrade defenses and clan castle mainly, while elixir is used for army power. I would prioritize on elixir first, as a larger and stronger army would be better, since defenses being one level higher does not do much good for you. In raids, you should look for Gold and dark elixir villages, while elixir should be the same as the cost of training your army. With a stronger and larger army, you would see more success in your raids, being able to attack stronger villages with better loot.